# AssertionError: would build wheel with unsupported tag ('cp310', 'cp310', 'linux_x86_64')

Tags: python, numpy

I've got this message when I try to install numpy using Python 3.10.

How to fix this?

```
  Copying numpy.egg-info to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/numpy-1.19.3-py3.10.egg-info
  running install_scripts
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/walenty/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
      main()
    File "/home/walenty/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 263, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "/home/walenty/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 204, in build_wheel
      return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-plb3t7s6/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 211, in build_wheel
      return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-plb3t7s6/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 197, in _build_with_temp_dir
      self.run_setup()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-plb3t7s6/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 248, in run_setup
      super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-plb3t7s6/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 142, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 508, in <module>
      setup_package()
    File "setup.py", line 500, in setup_package
      setup(**metadata)
    File "/tmp/pip-install-p3yq92pw/numpy/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 169, in setup
      return old_setup(**new_attr)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-plb3t7s6/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 165, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-plb3t7s6/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 328, in run
      impl_tag, abi_tag, plat_tag = self.get_tag()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-plb3t7s6/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 278, in get_tag
      assert tag in supported_tags, "would build wheel with unsupported tag {}".format(tag)
  AssertionError: would build wheel with unsupported tag ('cp310', 'cp310', 'linux_x86_64')
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
Failed to build numpy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Comment: I had the same error with `pip` and OSX. I was able to build from source getting `RuntimeWarning: NumPy 1.21.0 may not yet support Python 3.10`

Comment: This is a bug and it will be fixed soon. See https://github.com/pypa/wheel/issues/354

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a bug in python 3.10, a workaround is installing numpy with the `--no-use-pep517` flag. E.g.: `pip3.10 install numpy --no-use-pep517`

There's a fix for this on the way though, so just waiting is an option as well.

Comment: Have been looking for this solution for days! Thank you