# Can't install scikit-learn on mac

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, pip

I am trying to install scikit-learn and scipy packages in Python. I've already installed NumPy and Pandas successfully. Then I used following command:

```
pip install scikit-learn
```

and I received following error:

```
File "/private/tmp/pip-build-env-w7wmv28v/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 278, in get_tag
                      assert tag in supported_tags, "would build wheel with unsupported tag {}".format(tag)
                  AssertionError: would build wheel with unsupported tag ('cp39', 'cp39', 'macosx_11_0_universal2')
                  [end of output]
      
              note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
              ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
            Failed to build numpy
            ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
            [end of output]
      
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error
      
      × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
      │ exit code: 1
      ╰─> See above for output.
      
      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I am using python 3.9.10, and a mac computer. What should I do?

Comment: pip3.9 install numpy --no-use-pep517 this can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/66908804/9052234

Comment: thanks! i installed anaconda and it solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?:

```
pip install sklearn
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't solve :(